# Xamarin.Forms page transition lagg penalty

Tags: c#, performance, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a MasterDetail app that every time i click a menu item to change page, it has some lag on the **android**. Code for onClick transition:

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
MasterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
IsPresented = false;
```

My page calls a custom rendered TabbedPage with child ContentPages. The only way to have 100% smooth navigation is if i load just a plain empty page.

**Question**:

Is it really impossible to achieve 100% smootheness with Xamarin.Forms? My app is still trivial and makes me wonder what will happen when i scale it.

***PS***

I follow the guidelines so far and i have optimized my renderers and API calls to a good extend. None of these affect my code.

Comment: Have you tried AOT compilation? It improves performance a lot. Are you using Fast renderers and Layout compression? Do you experiment lags on every device you use?

Comment: There's performance penalty in every device with some differences based on hardware(some lag more, some less). I don't have the option to enable AOT from android build settings for some reason, so i put AOT = true on the project.csproj file. Layout compression?

Comment: Layout Compression is a new feature available in Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0, used to eliminate unneeded renderers from layout hierarchy.

Comment: Adding Fast renderers and Layout compression made my lists faster indeed but the navigation is not changing behavior. Maybe loading nested hierarchies is something that inevitably will lagg in XF

Comment: I would suggest to create a simple repro sample and commit a bug. Beside this, check your custom page renderer, the perfomance issue might hide in there.